# Trim leading zeroes with char in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, trim

I need to write a function that removes the first leading zero(s) in a string. The position of the first zero(s) can vary.

Example one:

```
0000900 needs to become 900
```

Example two:

```
A0000900 needs to become A900
```

Example three:

```
ABCD00090ABC0D needs to become ABCD90ABC0D
```

Example four:

```
ABC0D00090ABC0D needs to become ABCD00090ABC0D
```

So the first leading zeroes, regardless of starting position have to be removed.

I tried this:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(255)=  '0002981K0K'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@input, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', @input), LEN(@input))
```

But this only leads to `2981K0K`, which is good. But whenever I add a non-numeric value in front (let's say `A`), the query doesn't see the first leading zeroes anymore and results into `A0002981K0K`

Comment: What happens with `AB0C00D000900`?

Comment: It should turn into ABC00D000900 (remove the first zero).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?
For the second result, I split the string into two parts with prefix zero, then combine the first parts with substring follow prefix zero of second part.
 For the AB000C00D000900, it will be split to AB and 000C00D000900
then combine AB and C00D000900 into ABC00D000900

```
  ;WITH tb(S) AS (
    SELECT 'ABCD00090ABC0D' UNION
    SELECT '0000900' UNION
    SELECT 'K0000900800' UNION
    SELECT 'A0000900' UNION
    SELECT 'AB00CD00900' UNION
    SELECT 'AB000C00D000900' UNION
    SELECT '0002981K0K'
    )
    SELECT s,STUFF(s,PATINDEX('%0%',s),PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',s)-PATINDEX('%0%',s),'')
          ,c.l+SUBSTRING(c.r,PATINDEX('%[^0]%',c.r),len(c.r))
    FROM tb
    CROSS APPLY(VALUES(PATINDEX('%0%',s),LEFT(s,PATINDEX('%0%',s)-1),SUBSTRING(s,PATINDEX('%0%',s),LEN(s)))) c(b,l,r)
```

```
s                                    
--------------- -------------------- ------------------------------
0000900         900                  900
0002981K0K      2981K0K              2981K0K
A0000900        A900                 A900
AB00CD00900     AB900                ABCD00900
AB000C00D000900 AB900                ABC00D000900
ABCD00090ABC0D  ABCD90ABC0D          ABCD90ABC0D
K0000900800     K900800              K900800
```

if you do not want use cross apply, you can change the query to :

```
    SELECT s,LEFT(s,PATINDEX('%0%',s)-1)+SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(s,PATINDEX('%0%',s),LEN(s)),PATINDEX('%[^0]%', SUBSTRING(s,PATINDEX('%0%',s),LEN(s))),len(s))
    FROM tb
```

Comment: `0000900800` -> `900800`, I think (the same as all the examples with 9 and zero after).  Like number 3

Comment: The real question is zeros mixed in with letters -- `AB00CD00900` -> `ABCD900` or `ABCD00900`?  Your code gives `AB900` which I think is wrong.

Comment: Thx for the replies guys. I think it works good but Hogan you're right. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: It does matter actually,  thx alot. Didn't think it would be an issue, but actually it is. Not sure if this statement can also be used when zeros are mixed with letters?

Comment: AB00CD00900 should return ABCD00900 but it returns AB900

Comment: That should not be hard to fix `PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',s)` needs to look for not `0` and should start after the first 0 is found.

Comment: @ocaj90  I changed my answer, Does the second result is helpful?

Comment: Really helpful thanks @Nolan! The problem with this though is, is that it can't be used within a scalar-valued function in SQL server, right?

Comment: @Hogan can you be more specific? not 0 as in <>0? I can't get it to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ocaj90 I added a new query had removed the cross apply statement. the orignal cross apply only use to set an alias partial result element

Comment: @ocaj90  Not 0 in regular expressions -- I believe that is `[^0]`  Find a regex tester online and debug.